# Viewing a greeting screen for a specific period of time

Tags: dart, flutter

I have been trying to find any information about creating a Widget that disappears after a period of time. I am trying to create a greeting page that appears once the app runs and disappears after a couple of seconds; navigating to my home page afterwards.

What is the correct direction in order to get this done?

I understand how to use showDialog with buttons, but I want the greetings view to be the very first view when the app starts, so how to correctly use showDialog?

```
void main() {
  runApp( new MaterialApp(
   home: new SignIn(),//how to integrate showDialog with my flow
))
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The full code of a transition between a 'Greeting page' and your home using PageRouteBuilder and NavigatorState.pushReplacement :

[image: greeting]

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new Greeting(),
  ));
}

class Greeting extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GreetingState createState() => new _GreetingState();
}

class _GreetingState extends State<Greeting> {
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    new Timer(const Duration(seconds: 5), onClose);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Align(
          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          child: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text(
                "Hello you !",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
              ),
              new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text("Here's a unicorn for your"),
                  new Image.network(
                    "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/3b/06/ef/3b06efe25fed62de2960090ff2b8d83a--cute-cartoon-drawings-drawings-of.jpg",
                    height: 42.0,
                    width: 42.0,
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          )),
    );
  }

  void onClose() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(new PageRouteBuilder(
        maintainState: true,
        opaque: true,
        pageBuilder: (context, _, __) => new Home(),
        transitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
        transitionsBuilder: (context, anim1, anim2, child) {
          return new FadeTransition(
            child: child,
            opacity: anim1,
          );
        }));
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
        title: new Text("Home"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Timer and the Navigator for such a thing.

We can think of a stateful TimedWidget, invoked with
`showDialog(child: new TimedWidget(), context: context);`

And the code of that widget would have something like :

```
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = new Timer(const Duration(seconds: 5), onCloseDialog);
  }

  void onCloseDialog() {
    if (mounted) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    }
  }
```

**Edit :**

You may have noticed that you can't do showDialog/NavigatorState.push inside the build method.
If you really want to have your page/popin directly without pressing any buttons, you have a few solutions.

For a page, you can think of directly loading your GreetingPage into the runApp.
And then, the Greeting page will redirect after a few seconds to the according home.
Typically, you'd have something like this in your GreetingPage :

```
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    new Timer(const Duration(seconds: 5), onClose);
  }

  void onClose() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(new PageRouteBuilder(
        maintainState: true,
        opaque: true,
        pageBuilder: (context, _, __) => new Home(),
        transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
        transitionsBuilder: (context, anim1, anim2, child) {
          return new FadeTransition(
            child: child,
            opacity: anim1,
          );
        }));
  }
```

Easier, for a dialog you can have use another timer to delay the apparition of your dialog by a frame.
Here you'd have this :

```
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    new Timer(const Duration(), () {
      showDialog(context: context, child: new SimpleDialog(
        title: new Text("Hello world"),
      ));
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you I get the general idea, but I am confused on where exactly to use the showDialog function, I am adding a sample code in the OP.

Comment: I edited the post to provide a bit more explanations.

Comment: The first solution I could not get it to work. The second one however is working but even after specifying the duration the dialog does not disappear until after I touch the screen.

Comment: I figured out that Duration controls how long would it takes the app to start showing the dialog not how long should the dialog last. Should not this be the other way around ?

Comment: The timer in my code is to delay the dialog apparition by one frame. Due to the fact that you can't do showDialog within the build method.

You still have to do another timer to close that dialog. Which will consist of a `new Timer(const Duration(seconds: 5), () => Navigator.of(context).pop());`